# plotBands Makes the plotLines Disappears highchart

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

when i use the plotbands between two points on the xaxis and the draw a line between these two points using pointLines it never appears but if you do the same on yAxis every thing works just fine 
here is my code

```
  $(function () {
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container'
    },
    xAxis: {        
        plotBands: [{ // mark the weekend
            color: 'rgba(68, 170, 213, 0.2)',
            from: Date.UTC(2010, 0, 2),
            to: Date.UTC(2010, 0, 4)
        }],
        plotLines:[{
         value: Date.UTC(2010, 0, 3),
                  color: 'green',
                  dashStyle: 'shortdash',
                  width: 2,
        }],
        plotLines:[{
         value: Date.UTC(2010, 0, 6),
                  color: 'green',
                  dashStyle: 'shortdash',
                  width: 2,
        }],
        tickInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000, // one day
        type: 'datetime'
    },
    yAxis:{
        plotLines:[{
            value : 200,
            color: 'green',
                  dashStyle: 'shortdash',
                  width: 2,
        }] ,
         plotBands: [{ // mark the weekend
            color: 'rgba(68, 170, 213, 0.2)',
            from: 150,
            to: 250,
        }],  
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4 , 255.7],
        pointStart: Date.UTC(2010, 0, 1),
        pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000
       }]
   });
 });​
```

i also jsFiddle it http://jsfiddle.net/MsCqR/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is that if you want to set 2 plotLines you have to pass them thrue an array, like the following code:

```
plotLines:[{
    value: Date.UTC(2010, 0, 3),
    color: 'green',
    dashStyle: 'shortdash',
    width: 2,
}, {
   value: Date.UTC(2010, 0, 6),
   color: 'green',
   dashStyle: 'shortdash',
   width: 2,
}]
```

**How to add more than 1 plot line**: **[LINK1](http://jsfiddle.net/MsCqR/4/)**
**How to edit plotLines' zindex**: **[LINK2](http://jsfiddle.net/MsCqR/5/)**

Comment: how about editing the zIndex for the lines and put them over the Band

Comment: @MinaGabriel Look the second fiddle.

Comment: i have another hard question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10421177/plotbands-target-one-of-the-two-panes

Comment: i appreciate  if you can help

Comment: zIndex editing was powerful solution. Thanks :) You made my day!

Answer (score 0):

Use zIndex to plotlines or plotbands posicition...

```
            plotLines: [{
                width: 3,
                color: "#808080"
            },{
                value: "200",
                width: 4,
                color: "#FF0000",
        zIndex: 4}],
```