# plotbands target one of the two panes

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

hi i am using the two panes chart http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/candlestick-and-volume
 i then put a plodBands to that chart , what happened is the Band affect both yAxis like in here http://jsfiddle.net/6sqEd/ what i have noticed is this chart has only one xAxis .

How can i make this PlotBands arget only the first yAxis Not BOTH ???

here is the code :

```
    $(function() {
   $.getJSON('http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=aapl-  ohlcv.json&callback=?', function(data) {

    // split the data set into ohlc and volume
    var ohlc = [],
        volume = [],
        dataLength = data.length;

    for (i = 0; i < dataLength; i++) {
        ohlc.push([
            data[i][0], // the date
            data[i][1], // open
            data[i][2], // high
            data[i][3], // low
            data[i][4] // close
        ]);

        volume.push([
            data[i][0], // the date
            data[i][5] // the volume
        ])
    }


    // create the chart
    chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            alignTicks: false
        },

        rangeSelector: {
            selected: 5
        },

        title: {
            text: 'AAPL Historical'
        },
        xAxis:[{
            plotBands : [{
                from : 1115856000000,
                to : 1128384000000,
                color : 'rgba(68, 170, 213, 0.2)',
                label : {
                    text : 'Last quarter\'s value range'
                }
            }]


        }],

        yAxis: [{
            title: {
                text: 'OHLC'
            },
            height: 200,
            lineWidth: 2
        }, {
            title: {
                text: 'Volume'
            },
            top: 300,
            height: 100,
            offset: 0,
            lineWidth: 2
        }],

        series: [{
            type: 'candlestick',
            name: 'AAPL',
            data: ohlc,

        }, {
            type: 'column',
            name: 'Volume',
            data: volume,
            yAxis: 1,

          }]
       });
       });
     });​
```

Comment: You should accept the answer below. It's a pretty good answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you add a plotBand to the yAxis you can set just higger and lower points.
If you put the plotBand on the xAxis it will be displayed on all yAxis.
So if you want to plot just on the first axis probably you have to make a new serie with the same style of a plotBand an add to it.

**First**: You've to create an area serie from the start date to the end date wich all values will be the same of the maximum value of the pane. In my example it's 800.
**Second**: Make sure the maximum value is higher than the highest value of your serie. II didn't do it in my example, so you have to do it on your code.
**Third**: Remove the serie from the legend and from the tooltip setting the enableMouseTracking and showInLegend to false.

**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/ricardolohmann/6sqEd/5/)**

Comment: can you give me more details ?

Comment: @MinaGabriel Sure, look to my edited answer, I'll explain how to do  it.

Comment: Thanks it seems like the answer but if you need to loop and add more plotBands to the chart what do you do ?

Comment: like adding this area as FROM -TO like plotBands

Comment: You can do the same thing or when the chart is rendered use chart.addPlotBand(plotBandOptions) passing thrue the param a plotBand object.